# Confused about Promise,why prints "1 2 11 22" and not "1 2 22 11"?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am not very good at Promise in Javascript, And today I saw a question which makes me confused for a while, here is the code:

```js
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res();
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log(1);
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      res();
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(2);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(22);
      });
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(11);
  });
```

I think the result should be 1 2 22 11, But I was wrong, the real answer is **1 2 11 22**

why? please help me thank you!

Comment: Because you don't `return` the `new Promise`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand this Promise execution order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270410/how-to-understand-this-promise-execution-order)

Answer (score -1):

we can separate it into three parts: A, B, C

```js
new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    // Part A
    res()
}).then(()=>{
    // Part B
    console.log(1)
    new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        // Part B-1
        res()
    }).then(()=>{
        // Part B-2
        console.log(2)
    }).then(()=>{
        // Part B-3
        console.log(22)
    })
}).then(()=>{
    // Part C
    console.log(11)
})
```

it starts by print **1**
then the inside Promise was resolved(Part B-1), two tasks have been inserted into task queue:

1. Part B-2 `console.log(2)`
2. Part C `console.log(11)`

then execute the first task: print **2**, when Done, another task has been added at the end of the task queue, the new task queue looks like:

1. Part C `console.log(11)`
2. Part B-3 `console.log(22)`
   then execute the task by order: print **11** and **22**

so the result is **1 2 11 22**

by the way, if we want the order **1 2 22 11**  we can add keyword *return* in front of the inside promise:

```js
new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    res()
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(1)
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        res()
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log(2)
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log(22)
    })
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(11)
})
```

the result is **1 2 22 11**